# How to change color and background of whole web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I need to change the colors and backgrounds of an existing shopping cart web site so that all backgrounds are blue and all texts are black.

When the mouse is over an anchor element, its background should change to gray.

This site is designed using jquery, jquery plugins, jquery-ui, 
ASP.NET / Mono MVC3, Razor views. . jquery ui default theme is used but in may places colors and backgrounds are specified in non-jquery ui css files.

There are number of css files so changing all of them is lot of work.

How to implement this ? Is it possible to add some jquery or other plugin javascript code to page which makes such adjustment or other idea ?

It should be changed to use blue and black colors.
How to implement this ?

**Update**

Most css files are included in Razon Site.cshtml file which is master page for all files.
css files are static and appear in start of every page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/comp/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"
    type="text/css" title="ui-theme" />
<link href="/comp/Content/Css/jquery.ui.menubar.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />

<link href="/comp/Scripts/jBreadCrumb/Styles/BreadCrumb.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="/comp/Scripts/Pikachoose/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/comp/Scripts/jcarousel-0.2/skins/tango/skin.css" />
<link href="/comp/Content/Css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

jquery-ui menubar, breadcrumb, fancybox, pikachoose jcarousel plugins are used.

Comment: you could put all ur styles in a css file and load them after all the existing css files have loaded. but this will cause a performance hit .

Comment: you are using Layout or master page? change the colors in that main file, for e.g <body bgcolor="red">

Comment: Thank you. There are lot of styles. Maybe is it better to allow javascript to do this automatically? If yes, how to run javascript after page is loaded which will change styles or colors in DOM tree ?

Comment: @Andrus -NO. This must be taken care of by css. JS wasnt built for this.

Comment: @AltafSami `bgcolor` is deprecated. You shouldn't use that. You should use `style` if you must.

Comment: @Andrus you say there are multiple CSS files, but could you elaborate? Is there a CSS files *per page*? Is there a CSS file which is included on all pages?

Comment: Same css files are included in all pages. I updated question about this and provided more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you wouldn't use JavaScript for this because it would create extra load time, wouldn't work for users with JavaScript disabled, and is entirely unnecessary.

To change the background colour of a page you'd find the `body` tag and add or change its `background` (or `background-color`) property:

```
body {
    background:#F00; /* #F00 being the hex representation of "red" */
}
```

Your website may have multiple CSS files, but it should have one global CSS file for styles which are already applied to all pages. If this *isn't* the case, you should really consider combining any commonly used styles into one file and including that on all of your pages.

If changing your `body` styling *doesn't* change anything, you'll need to find out where the site is currently getting its background from. If there are two files with `body { background:...; }` declared, the latter included CSS file will override the former. That said, you can easily find which colour is being pulled through by consulting your browser's Element Inspector to find the body's "computed style".

**Edit:** based on your latest edit, going by the file names "/comp/Content/Css/Site.css" is the file you'd want to change.

Comment: Should I copy all styles to site.css keeping same name and change colors there ?

Comment: Look for `body` in your Site.css file. If you can't find anything, add the snippet I've given to your CSS file - this will apply the background to your page.

Comment: Pages contain lot of elements. They have their own background and a:hover colors specified in different css files. As far as I know changing body background will not change other element backgrounds.

Comment: Elements on your page should have transparent backgrounds. If not they probably have different coloured backgrounds for a reason. If you want to remove them all, simply remove all occurrences of `background` and `background-color` and add it to the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing background-color for page can be achieved by applying style to body tag, but there are good chances that your page will have wired fonts because of existing css, thus asking you to push in more time finding individual fix then creating new one,

There is no shortcut to do this kind of work without good chances of failing and ending up spending more time in fixing.

Better would be:-

Create copy of css files and make you changes there, now change path to point to this new css.

If by any chance you are using themes create a new theme, if not consider having themes.

Answer (score 0):

KISS principle:
Put this in a `.js` file and refer to it in the `head` or put it in the `head` tag as a script.

JavaScript:

```
function colorset(x,y)
{
    document.body.style.background = x;    
    document.getElementById('ElementID').style.color = y;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:colorset('#000','#fff');">white on black</a>
```